# AngularJS $http.head is showing a status code of 0 despite a successful 200 response

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a directive that will take a link, makes a HEAD request to check if the link returns a 200 code, and if it does, then sticks that link into an iframe src.

But, what I'm finding is that $http is giving me errors, despite the fact that the network tab of my chrome & firefox debuggers are showing me the server responds with a status code of 200.

Plnkr here to demonstrate:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dgn5E8u3WYijd73kKtAz?p=preview

```
angular.module('testHead', [])
  .controller('testHeadController', function($http) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.results = "waiting";

      vm.getHead = function() {
        $http.head('http://www.apple.com/')
          .then(
            function(response) {
              console.log("response", response)
            },
            function(error) {
              console.log("error", error)
            }
          )
      }
});
```

Open up the preview in full screen with the console open and you'd be able to see what I mean...

[image: Status code of 200, with angular's error showing a status code of 0]

Does anybody know why this is occurring? Is it a bug in AngularJS? Why won't AngularJS show the status code that the browser is receiving?
Thanks!

Comment: Browser successfully fetches the document. Checks for CORS access and decides to block the request. Browser sends "failed" response to application instead of actual document as a security feature. That's why you see 200 in browser and 0 in Angular.js.

Comment: The ironic thing about this - to me - is that this is a HEAD request. Which means that I'm not interested in the content, only the headers. And I can see that I've got those already, I just can't figure out how to get to them in AngularJS. And yes, if I were to use a url that I'd expect to get a 404 from, I'd see the net tab gives me the 404 status code, but I still get 0 in AngularJS.

Comment: As long as server doesn't explicitly allow using CORS headers you can't access any part of the response in JavaScript, including headers and even status. That's by design. If server is yours you can add CORS header to allow request.

Comment: So I can see the headers & response code in the firebug net tab, but I can't get access to it via JavaScript. Time to try something different then... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser successfully fetches the document. That's why you see `200` in developer console.

Then, browser checks for CORS access to decide if caller JavaScript is allowed to see the response. (It doesn't matter if it is Angular.js or anything else)

In this case, browser sees no CORS header, meaning the contents of ajax is not allowed for this domain. So, even browser got `200` from server it reports it as `failed` to caller script because it shouldn't be accessed. That's why you see 200 in browser and 0 in Angular.js.

As long as server doesn't explicitly allow using CORS headers you can't access any part of the response in JavaScript, including headers and even status. That's by design.

If server is yours you can add CORS header to allow request.

Answer (score 0):

You already saw the error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". That means you cannot access a domain from another domain in Javascript, even with  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set in your HTTP header. This is a server side issue. Apple should have blocked cross origin access.

In your case, you want to check if the URL can be inserted into an iframe. Just checking the return code is enough. If it's 200, you can go ahead and insert it into the iframe.

BTW, if you want to know more about HTTP access control, you can refer to this page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Hi Chong. That's basically what I'm asking. AngularJS is telling me that the response code is 0, whereas I can see that the response code in the net tab is 200. How would I get the "actual" response code?

Comment: If it's 200, you can put that URL in iframe. It should work. Doesn't it?